# How do keep calling API using jQuery ajax if failed until three times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my jQuery ajax sample code

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.test.com',
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data
})
.done(function(returnObj) {
  return returnObj;
})
.fail(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

If failed, I will console log the error message, but how do I keep calling until three times failed and stop calling again and alert some message?

Comment: retry ajax -- https://gist.github.com/aeurielesn/2511005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, (using recursion)

```
var counter = 1;

var ajaxFunc = function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.test.com',
      method: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(returnObj) {
      return returnObj;
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      counter++;
      if(counter<=3) ajaxFunc();
    });
}
ajaxFunc(); // first call
```

Answer (score 2):

Leveraging promises, you could just do it this way. Might not be particularly elegant, but it works quite well and is very readable:

```
var func = function() {
   return $.ajax(...);
};


func() //call 1
  .then(null,function() { return func(); }) //call 2
  .then(null,function() { return func(); }) //call 3
  .then(null,function() { console.log('3 times'); })
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using jQuery less than 1.8, you'll have to change `.then` to `.pipe`

```
var repeat = function(request,times) {
    var r = request();
    while( times > 0) {
       r = r.then(null,function() { return request(); })
       times--;
    }

    return r;
}

repeat($.ajax.bind(null,{url:'https://www.google.com'}),10)
.then(
   function() {
      console.log('success!');
   },
   function() { 
      console.log('failed 10 times'); 
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, really appreciated! but how about not three, is ten times? I am going to repeat ten times?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.test.com',
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data
  tryCount : 1,
  retryLimit : 3,
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, err){
       if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
           console.log("error")
           this.tryCount++;
           $.ajax(this);
       } else {
               console.log("max number ...");
              }
            }
})
.done(function(returnObj) {
  return returnObj;
})
.fail(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```